# Ho to add ajax to voting buttons and refresh result div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to implement facebook-linke interaction with buttons voting. I have the following code for my reviews page;

```
% @school_reviews.each do |school_review| %>                   
      <div class="widget-box ">                                           
        <div class="widget-header widget-header-small padding-16">                              

          <div class="widget-toolbar no-border">
            <span class="vbar"></span>                  
                    <span class="vbar"></span>
                    <small class="theme-color"> <%= school_review.created_at.strftime(" %d-%b %Y  ") %> </small>      
                  <span class="vbar"></span>                  
                  <span class="vbar"></span>
                  <% if  can? :destroy, school_review %>
                    <%= link_to(school_review, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'red') do %>
                      <i class="icon-trash bigger-130"></i>
                    <% end %> 
                  <% end %> 
            <span class="vbar"></span>            
          </div>                                                
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body">
          <div class="widget-main padding-16">
              <%= simple_format(school_review.description) %>  
              <div class="">
                <span class="review-votes theme-color"> 
                 <span id= <%= "up_votes_count-#{school_review.id}" %>> <%= school_review.get_likes.size  %> </span>
                 <span> 
                   <%= link_to vote_up_path(id: school_review.id), remote: true do %>           
                      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up theme-color "></i>
                    <% end %>
                  </span>
                </span>
                <span class="review-votes theme-color">
                  <span id= <%= "down_votes_count-#{school_review.id}" %>> <%= school_review.get_dislikes.size %> </span>
                  <span> 
                    <%= link_to vote_down_path(id: school_review.id), remote: true do %>        
                      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down theme-color "></i>
                    <% end %> 
                  </span>                
                </span>
              </div>            
          </div>  
        </div>                         
      </div>
      <div class="hr hr-12"></div>
    <% end %>
```

and vote_up.js.erb looks like this;

```
getElementById(<%= "up_votes_count-#{@school_review.id}" %>).html(<%= "@school_review.get_likes.size" %>);
```

and vote_down.js.erb looks like this;

```
getElementById(<%= "down_votes_count-#{@school_review.id}"%>).html("<%= @school_review.get_dislikes.size %>");
```

However the vote counts are not being refreshed. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you need to follow these steps:

a. Create a route for your custom action. You have already done that with down_vote_path and up_vote_path.

b. Add remote:true option to your button from which you want to call the ajax:

```
<%= button_tag vote_up_path(id: school_review.id), remote: true do %>                    
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up theme-color "></i>
<% end %>
```

c. In your controller method vote_up you need to add respond_to block

```
def vote_up
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  @school.update(#your attribute)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to your_path}
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

d. In your vote_up.js.erb file you need to update `<%= school_review.get_likes.size  %>. For this first of all you'll have to change your html and give some id or class to the portion you want to update

```
<span id="up_vote_count"><%= school_review.get_likes.size  %></span>
```

Now you have something to target inside your js.erb file so you can simply do

```
$("#up_vote_count").html("<%=j @school.likes.size >"); #need to replace the ruby part with code which'll give your like count.
```

This will update your span with new like counts. You can follow the same approach for down voting too.

Edit:

try:

```
$("<%=j up_votes_count-#{@school_review.id} %>").html("<%= @school_review.get_likes.size %>");
```

Comment: @Acacia did you edit your question because i can't see error in your question

Comment: I rolled back because it did not work. There is iteration so all the child companents get the same id and cannot refresh specifically any one of them

Comment: @Acacia you need to give them specific ids. You can give them different ids by `<span id="up_vote_count_<%=school.id %>"><%= school_review.get_likes.size  %></span>` and then target that id inside your js.erb file

Comment: Are you able to alert from your js.erb files?

Comment: @Acacia check updated answer and open your browser console and look for any error in ajax request

Comment: i got it to work with the help from a previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129173/rails-autorefresh-div-on-clicking-voting-button-using-ajax