# Rails autorefresh div on clicking voting button using ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I wish to auto refresh a div calculating the total number of votes after someone has clicked the vote button. The vote is registered but the refreshing does not happen.

I have done something like this;

```
<% @school_reviews.each do |school_review| %>                   
  <div class="widget-box ">                                           
    <div class="widget-header widget-header-small padding-16">                              

      <div class="widget-toolbar no-border">
        <span class="vbar"></span>                  
                <span class="vbar"></span>
                <small class="theme-color"> <%= school_review.created_at.strftime(" %d-%b %Y  ") %> </small>      
              <span class="vbar"></span>                  
              <span class="vbar"></span>
              <% if  can? :destroy, school_review %>
                <%= link_to(school_review, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'red') do %>
                  <i class="icon-trash bigger-130"></i>
                <% end %> 
              <% end %> 
        <span class="vbar"></span>            
      </div>                                                
    </div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main padding-16">
          <%= simple_format(school_review.description) %>  
          <div class="voting-banner">
            <span class="review-votes theme-color"> 
             <span id= <%= "up_votes_count-#{school_review.id}" %>> <%= school_review.get_likes.size  %> </span>
             <span> 
               <%= link_to vote_up_path(id: school_review.id), remote: true do %>           
                  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up theme-color "></i>
                <% end %>
              </span>
            </span>
            <span class="review-votes theme-color">
              <span id= <%= "down_votes_count-#{school_review.id}" %>> <%= school_review.get_dislikes.size %> </span>
              <span> 
                <%= link_to vote_down_path(id: school_review.id), remote: true do %>        
                  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down theme-color "></i>
                <% end %> 
              </span>                
            </span>
          </div>            
      </div>  
    </div>                         
  </div>
  <div class="hr hr-12"></div>
<% end %>
```

and vote_up.js.erb looks like this;

```
getElementById(<%= "up_votes_count-#{@school_review.id}" %>).html("<%= @school_review.get_likes.size %>");
```

while vote_down.js.erb looks like thisl

```
getElementById(<%= "down_votes_count-#{@school_review.id}"%>).html("<%= @school_review.get_dislikes.size %>");
```

and the controller action look like this;

```
def vote_up
  @school_review = SchoolReview.find(params[:id])
  @school_review.liked_by current_user

   respond_to do |format|
      #format.html {redirect_to school_reviews_path}
      format.js { }
    end    
end

def vote_down
  @school_review = SchoolReview.find(params[:id])
  @school_review.downvote_from current_user

   respond_to do |format|
      #format.html {redirect_to school_reviews_path}
      format.js { }
    end    
end
```

In the console, i get

```
    GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/vote_up [HTTP/1.1 200 OK  290ms]
GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/vote_up [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified  86ms]
```

Thank you

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById` instead of just `getElementById` in your view. Open a console in a browser, copy your ajax response and run it in the console to see what is wrong with your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQuery**

You're getting confused [between JQuery & pure JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283098/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jquery)

--

Your call of `getElementByID` is a javascript call - and [needs to be attached to the `document`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) object, as mentioned by [`Octopus-Paul`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_the_Octopus), so that's your first problem

The second issue is you're calling `html` on the respective `objects`. [`.html` is a JQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/html/); the javascript equivalent being [`.innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

You'll be better doing this:

```
#app/views/controller/action.html.erb
$("<%=j 'up_votes_count-#{@school_review.id}' %>").html("<%=j @school_review.get_likes.size %>");
```

This uses pure JQuery, which should allow you to append the respective data to your page

Comment: am getting NoMethodError - undefined method `gsub' for 16:Fixnum:
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb:30:in `escape_javascript' which i think is due to the ID number-16

Comment: Okay, let me refactor for you :)